# Using Polymer iron-ajax in repeating template

Tags: polymer

How do I load a json file and use the data in a repeating template? This code doesn't produce anything:

```
<dom-module id="name-list">
    <template>
        <iron-ajax auto url="names.json" handleAs="json" lastResponse="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{data}}">
            <div>First name: <span>{{item.firstName}}</span></div>
            <div>Last name: <span>{{item.lastName}}</span></div>
        </template>
    </template>
</dom-module>

<script>
    Polymer({
        is: "name-list"
    });
</script>
```

Here's my json file (Edit: corrected after vasek's reply):

```
{
    [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },{
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to have the following:

```
<div>First name: <span>John</span></div>
<div>Last name: <span>Smith</span></div>
<div>First name: <span>Jane</span></div>
<div>Last name: <span>Doe</span></div>
```

I'm including iron-ajax elsewhere in my code. I've already tested the general functionality. It works, just not in the context of data-binding.

Comment: Your corrected JSON code is still wrong. Remove the highest-level object.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly as vasek says, your JSON is incorrect. `dom-repeat` needs an array to iterate over and your JSON is currently returning an object. Secondly, you are accessing the properties on the `iron-ajax` element incorrectly. As the [docs](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/properties.html#property-name-mapping) state

> In order to configure camel-case properties of elements using attributes, dash- case should be used in the attribute name.

You are trying to set `handleAs` and `lastResponse`. In order to do these you need to change them to the dash-case:

```
<iron-ajax auto url="names.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{data}}"></iron-ajax>
```

Otherwise, everything else should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Your json file is in wrong format. It should be like this:

```
    [
        {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Smith"
        },
        {
            "firstName": "Jane",
            "lastName": "Doe"
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Gah! Of course! Still not working, though. When inspecting the element in Chrome, all I see there is #document-fragment.

Comment: @Squis Try to modify json file to: {"list": [...]}. And in template set items attribute to {{data.list}}.

Answer (score 1):

I was also stuck with a similar code, unfortunately the above answers didn't solve the issue for me. 
However, when I put the `<iron-ajax>` element after the `<template is="dom-repeat">`, it worked for me.